# Apply a discount code that has no value attached

Tags: discount

I would like to set a coupon code whereby when entered, customer will be receiving a free gift (instead of a monetary discount). I can create a discount code with 0 discount value but when applied, the discount code does not appear at checkout. IS there a way around this? 
Appreciate your help. Urgent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, I think you would need to add 100% discount on the specific product, you want to add, instead of 0 discount value... but then you still need to add the product to the cart somehow.

There are several plugins, that has this feature. You can try https://amasty.com/magento-free-gift.html